# Why does styling of one div affect another?

Tags: html, css

"Mid" and "right" are supposed to still be just under the nav bar, but when I vertically aligned my "left" text, "mid" and "right" vertically aligned along with it.

What do I need to change to have only "upper left" and "lower left" vertically aligned inside the images, while leaving "mid" and "right" still at their default position just below the nav bar?

[image]

```css
/* Main Content Seperation */

div.contentContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.left,
div.right {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.mid {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
/* Left Content */

div.left {
  height: 740px;
  color: white;
}
div.upperLeft,
div.lowerLeft {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
div.upperLeft {
  height: 366px;
  background-image: url("mainimg_macbook.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div.lowerLeft {
  height: 366px;
  background-image: url("mainimg_typing.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentContainer">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="upperLeft">
      <p class="left">Upper Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lowerLeft">
      <p class="left">Lower Left</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mid">
    <p>Mid</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>Right</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2sbpq3q/1/)

Another method is to just float the elements left.

**CSS**

```
/* Main Content Seperation */

div.contentContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.left,
div.right {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
div.mid {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left; // Floats Left
}
/* Left Content */

div.left {
  height: 740px;
  color: white;
  clear:none;
}
div.upperLeft,
div.lowerLeft {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
div.upperLeft {
  height: 366px;
  background: purple;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 366px;// Align Text to Center of Div
  text-align: center; // Center Text
}
div.lowerLeft {
  height: 366px;
  background-color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center; // Center Text
  line-height: 366px; // Align Text to Center of Div
}
```

Comment: yes i did wonder about that so I tried it, and it does work for raising the "mid" and "right" back to the top. but it causes another issue of floating my whole content to the left, so it is no longer horizontally in the middle of the screen

Comment: Could you provide a link to the website or anything? I'd like to help you solve this issue.

Comment: @oneman have you tried using a wrapper? It's a DIV that wraps around the body of your content. What this allows you to do is you can wrap you floating divs and fix your content to the center of the web page.

Comment: yes if I have done it correctly, my `div.contentContainer` is my wrapper, is that what you mean?

Comment: Okay, give me a little bit. I'm going to see if I can fix this up for ya.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127519/discussion-between-arlcode-and-oneman).